# ggplot2 only data which meets a condition

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm quite new to R and I've been struggling with producing a nice plot based on a specific condition.

I figured out how to use `scale_x_datetime` to modify the `xlim` and I figured out how to filter my data when I have one column. Then it's easy to plot but this is not what I need.

Now I have a dataset with 8 columns and a timestamp and I would like to plot values bigger or smaller than a particular threshold like in the example above but for each column, on one plot. However, the rows with those values are different in each column. I need something like an if statement but I'm looking for a way to do it within the plot itself, without filtering, creating new vectors etc.

This is the data:

```
timestamp           tempcore
2015-01-01 00:00:00 3.5
....
2015-01-31 23:45:00 7.5
```

The code I have so far:

```
library(scales)
filter <- mydata[mydata$tempcore<"4" | mydata$tempcore>"7",]

q <- ggplot(data = mydata) + 
   geom_point(data = filter, aes(x = timestamp, y= tempcore)) + 
   scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%d"), 
                    breaks = "1 day", 
                    limits = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 00:00:01", 
                                          "2015-01-31 23:59:59")))
```

Any suggestions?

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

```
structure(list(tempcore = c(7.852258, 4.95238, 4.945056, 4.969474, 
4.967037, 1.30402, 1.90476, 2.54945, 2.29304, 1.70208), Core14.2 = c(1.36508, 
1.36997, 1.25518, 1.28693, 1.18438, 1.13798, 1.17949, 1.16728, 
1.28693, 1.74848), Core14.3 = c(3.57998, 3.02808, 2.43224, 2.17583, 
2.08546, 1.8486, 1.78754, 1.77778, 1.8022, 1.68986), Core14.4 = c(4.564103, 
1.03785, 1.77534, 2.57876, 2.09768, 1.56776, 1.14286, 4.937724, 
4.869356, 4.664221), Core24.1 = c(1.0232, 1.0232, 1.03785, 1.02076, 
1.02564, 1.34798, 1.44566, 1.66789, 1.45544, 1.34554), Core.24.2 = c(2.00977, 
4.522583, 1.16484, 1.79487, 1.79732, 2.11966, 4.693522, 1.57998, 
9.89255, 3.16484), Glass.shade = c(3.96, 3.65, 4.23, 4.46, 4.19, 
3.77, 3.77, 4.31, 4.89, 6.75), AR7 = c(4.88, 4.88, 4.92, 4.92, 
4.92, 4.88, 4.88, 4.88, 4.84, 4.84), timestamp = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2015-01-01 00:00:00", 
"2015-01-01 00:15:00", "2015-01-01 00:30:00", "2015-01-01 00:45:00", 
"2015-01-01 01:00:00", "2015-01-01 01:15:00", "2015-01-01 01:30:00", 
"2015-01-01 01:45:00", "2015-01-01 02:00:00", "2015-01-01 02:15:00"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Core14.1", "Core14.2", "Core14.3", 
"Core14.4", "Core24.1", "Core.24.2", "Glass.shade", "AR7", "timestamp"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the picture - http://imgur.com/KOLtfgl

Comment: Please provide some data for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: In the question (you can edit it) and please use the output of `dput(yourdata)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I think it's the classic FAQ which is answered with change to long format:

```
mydata$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(mydata$timestamp, 
                               format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz ="GMT")

library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(mydata, id.vars = c("Glass.shade", "AR7", "timestamp"))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
q <- ggplot(data = DF[DF$value < 4 | DF$value > 7,],
            aes(x = timestamp, y= value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%d"), 
                   breaks = "1 day", 
                   limits = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 00:00:01", 
                                         "2015-01-31 23:59:59")))
print(q)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why do you use melt() only for those columns?

Comment: Well, would you also want to have `Glass.shade` depicted? Then don't specify it as an id column.